# Stacked bar graph in gnuplot with a CSV

Tags: linux, csv, gnuplot, data-visualization

I am new to gnuplot. I have been trying to plot the contents of CSV into various formats such as lines, boxes etc. However, with the volume and nature of data that I am having, the various fields/columns in the CSV have finite data at the same instance of time, due to which I see them getting overlapped in the plot due to obvious reasons. I want to ask if there is any way to see all the plots prominently, meaning, if multiple column data seem to share the same timestamp, is there a way I can see the smallest value at the front and the larger value at the back. One possible way could be stacked bar graphs.

Here is the snip of my input CSV:

```
TimeStamp,Score_1,Score_2,Score_3,Score_4
13:48:24, 8800, 8796, 4, 10
13:48:29, 1500, 8896, 4, 900
13:48:33, 8900, 8896, 4, 0
13:48:41, 8900, 8896, 4, 0
13:48:43, 6900, 8896, 4, 5000
13:48:55, 8900, 8896, 4, 0
13:49:21, 8900, 8500, 4, 0
13:49:29, 2900, 8000, 1000, 2000
13:50:29, 1900, 8896, 4000, 0
13:55:29, 9000, 8896, 1400, 0
13:52:29, 900, 8896, 4, 0
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
INPUT_FILE=ARG1
set datafile separator ','
set key autotitle columnhead
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1

plot INPUT_FILE using 1:2 with boxes, \
"" using 1:3 with boxes, \
"" using 1:4 with boxes, \

#plot INPUT_FILE using 1:2 with lines, \
#"" using 1:3 with lines, \
#"" using 1:4 with lines, \
```

Comment: Do any of [these examples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html) look like what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Plotting "with dots" will enable you to see all reasonably different X values for a given Y axis.  Reasonable is relative to scaling of the chart so set your yrange and zrange to display the minimum view required.

```
plot "blah" using 1:2 with dots
set xrange [0-10000]
set yrange [0-10000]
```

Another solution might be to preprocess your data i.e. sorting your score rows so the z-order always shows the lowest value in front.  This sounds easiest to me.

gnuplot supports 3D graphing so the use of splot combined with rotating the view and adding a z dimension to your data set you could achieve it as well.  This involves more work and still preprocessing your data and some logic around which rows are assigned to which z-order.

```
xrot=85
zrot=0
xview(xrot)=xrot
zview(zrot)=zrot
set view xview(xrot), zview(zrot), 1.3, 1
set size square

set output "blah.gif"
splot "blah.dat" using 1:2:6 with dots
```